# How to get GMT value for each timezone from knownTimeZoneNames

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimezone

I know how to get the list of known timezones: `[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]`.

But this method returns only time zone names (like "Africa/Abidjan").

How can I get GMT value (like `GMT+3` or `GMT-7`)for each of known time zone from that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, create an `NSTimeZone` instance for each time zone name and then get the `secondsFromGMT` property from each instance:

```
for (NSString *name in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) {
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:name];
    NSInteger gmtOffset = tz.secondsFromGMT;
}
```

The only outstanding issue would be converting from seconds to hours or hours/minutes, which shouldn't be too difficult.  Perhaps the default `[NSTimeZone description]` would return the correct information?

Comment: thank you very much. I actually found out the same way by reading apple documentation right now )))

Comment: Just remember that the results won't always be the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use method `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT`

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:secondsFromGMT];
NSMutableString *name = [NSMutableString stringWithString:timeZone.name];
if (! [name isEqualToString:@"GMT"])
{
    [name insertString:@":" atIndex:6];
}
return [NSString stringWithString:name];
```

Output will be `@"GMT+03:00"`. You don't need to construct it from hours and minutes.